# How to initialize VSTS extension data service in typescript file (Outside of HTML page)

Tags: typescript, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am just developing a build extension. During the build execution, extension loads some data by calling a third party web service and once build execution finished, I need to display them in the build summary page. For this purpose, I tried to use data service (VSS.SDK) to store the data and retrieve them back from the build summary page. But  since my extension **doesn't use a html page**, but only some TypeScripts, I 
didn't find a way to initialize the VSS.SDK data service as usual we use below the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    VSS.init( { 

    });
```

Is it possible for me to initialize VSS.SDK data service from out side of a html file (without using a html page)? Or is there another way to store and retrieve my data without using data service?. I really got stuck here for now two days but no luck with any try.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link for details: [Visual Studio Services Web Extension SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/vss-web-extension-sdk).

> **Types**
>
> - Types of VSS.SDK.js, controls and client services are available in    typings/vss.d.ts.
> - REST Client types for VSTS are available in    typings/tfs.d.ts
> - REST Client and extensibility types for Release    Management are available in typings/rmo.d.ts

**Using tsd**

Although TypeScript declare files do not exist at DefinitelyTyped repo, they can still be used through tsd.

1. First, make sure that the dependencies are loaded using below
   command:

   tsd install jquery knockout q --save
2. Next, run below command to get
   vss-web-extension-sdk types added to tsd.d.ts:

   tsd link
3. Finally, add only reference to typings/tsd.d.ts in your
   TypeScript files.

Comment: tsd is deprecated, use typings instead.